# My application won't download from windows phone store. Error: 80073cf9

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I published an app to windows phone store, but I cannot download it from there. I receive an error 80073cf9. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That's error 15609, ERROR_INSTALL_FAILED, "Install failed. Please contact your software vendor".  Well, that doesn't help us help you, other than that it doesn't have anything to do with the download, just the installation after the download.  Look in the Windows application event log, try another machine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just do not have this problem on windows phone 8.1